# Can't access WSO2 ESB proxy service thru its http endpoint URL

Tags: http, wso2, endpoint, wso2-esb

We have this WSO2 ESB proxy service that's accessible thru its https endpoint. I want to configure this service so that it will also be accessible via http. 
I checked the service configuration in the carbon management console and confirmed that both https and http endpoint were already enabled:
`https://10.20.0.20:8245/services/<service_name>
http://10.20.0.20:8282/services/<service_name>`

Also, the axis2.xml file in ESB_HOME}/repository/conf/axis2/ seems to be configured just fine.

```
<!-- ================================================= -->
<!--             Transport Ins (Listeners)             -->
<!-- ================================================= -->

<!-- the non blocking http transport based on HttpCore + NIO extensions -->
<transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOListener">
    <parameter name="port" locked="false">8280</parameter>
    <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
    <!--parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">hostname or IP address</parameter-->
    <!--parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">https://apachehost:port/somepath</parameter-->
    <parameter name="httpGetProcessor" locked="false">org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.NHttpGetProcessor</parameter>
    <!--<parameter name="priorityConfigFile" locked="false">location of priority configuration file</parameter>-->
    <parameter name="disableRestServiceDispatching" locked="false">true</parameter>
</transportReceiver>

<!-- the non blocking https transport based on HttpCore + SSL-NIO extensions -->
<transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOSSLListener">
    <parameter name="port" locked="false">8243</parameter>
    <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
    <!--parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">hostname or IP address</parameter-->
    <!--parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">https://apachehost:port/somepath</parameter-->
    <!--<parameter name="priorityConfigFile" locked="false">location of priority configuration file</parameter>-->
    <parameter name="httpGetProcessor" locked="false">org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.NHttpGetProcessor</parameter>
    <parameter name="disableRestServiceDispatching" locked="false">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="keystore" locked="false">
        <KeyStore>
            <Location>repository/resources/security/iaascol.jks</Location>
            <Type>JKS</Type>
            <Password>***</Password>
            <KeyPassword>rotcelloc</KeyPassword>
        </KeyStore>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="truststore" locked="false">
        <TrustStore>
            <Location>repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks</Location>
            <Type>JKS</Type>
            <Password>***</Password>
        </TrustStore>
    </parameter>
    <!--<parameter name="SSLVerifyClient">require</parameter>
        supports optional|require or defaults to none -->
</transportReceiver>
```

Port offset in ESB_HOME}/repository/conf/carbon.xml is set to 2.

```
<Offset>2</Offset>
```

I can't seem to access this proxy service thru its http endpoint URL. The version of WSO2 ESB is 4.5.0. Please let me know which configuration do I have to check / set. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Below is the proxy service config as well as netstat result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
  name="disbursement" statistics="disable"
  trace="enable" transports="https,http">
 <target>
    <inSequence>
        <property action="set" name="EXECUTION_CONTEXT"
            scope="default" type="STRING" value="disbursement"/>
        <property action="set"
            expression="fn:concat(//*[local-name()='Header']/*[local-name()='TrackingID'], '.xml')"
            name="DumpFileName" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <log category="INFO" level="full" separator=",">
            <property name="EVENT_TYPE" value="PROCESSING_STARTED"/>
            <property expression="get-property('DumpFileName')" name="FILENAME"/>
        </log>
        <property action="set" name="DumpFilePath" scope="default"
            type="STRING" value="/home/user1/data/disbursement/incoming"/>
        <class name="se.seman.wso2.mediator.WriteFile"/>
        <property action="set" name="TopicName" scope="default"
            type="STRING" value="VirtualTopic.seman.iaas.user1.topic.disbursement.out"/>
        <property action="set" name="ResultCode" scope="default"
            type="STRING" value="0"/>
        <!--
        TODO correct problem with xpath
        validate source="/default/xpath">
            <on-fail>
                <property action="set" name="ResultCode"
                    scope="default" type="STRING" value="100"/>
                <property action="set"
                    expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"
                    name="ResultMessage" scope="default"
                    type="STRING"
                    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Namespaces.user1.se:Cmf:InfoModel:FinancialManagement:Payment:Disbursment:0002"/>
                <log category="INFO" level="full" separator=",">
                    <property name="MESSAGE" value="Schema validation failed"/>
                    <property
                        expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"
                        name="ERROR_CODE"
                        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Namespaces.user1.se:Cmf:InfoModel:FinancialManagement:Payment:Disbursment:0002"/>
                    <property
                        expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"
                        name="ERROR_MESSAGE"
                        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Namespaces.user1.se:Cmf:InfoModel:FinancialManagement:Payment:Disbursment:0002"/>
                </log>
                <property action="set" name="RESPONSE"
                    scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            </on-fail>
            <schema key="conf:user1/ESBConfig/Common/NetPosti/resources/Disbursement_0002.xsd"/>
        </validate -->
        <log category="INFO" level="headers" separator=",">
            <property name="MESSAGE" value="Before Topic"/>
            <property expression="get-property('ERROR')" name="ERROR"/>
        </log>
        <filter xpath="get-property('ResultCode') = '0'">
            <then>
                <property action="set" name="ResultMessage"
                    scope="default" type="STRING" value="OK"/>
                <class name="se.seman.wso2.mediator.WriteActiveMQTopic"/>
            </then>
            <else/>
        </filter>
        <header action="remove" name="To"/>
        <property action="remove" name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2"/>
        <property action="set" name="RESPONSE" scope="default"
            type="STRING" value="true"/>
        <payloadFactory>
            <format>
                <disr:DisbursementResponse xmlns:disr="urn:Namespaces.user1.se:Service:FinancialManagement:Payment:Disbursement:Response:0001">
                    <disr:ResponseCode>$1</disr:ResponseCode>
                    <disr:Message>$2</disr:Message>
                </disr:DisbursementResponse>
            </format>
            <args>
                <arg expression="get-property('ResultCode')"/>
                <arg expression="get-property('ResultMessage')"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
        <log category="INFO" level="full" separator=","/>
        <send/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <log category="INFO" level="full" separator=",">
            <property name="MESSAGE" value="On the way back.."/>
        </log>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence>
        <log category="INFO" level="full" separator=",">
            <property name="MESSAGE" value="Error in Call!"/>
        </log>
        <property action="set" name="RESPONSE" scope="default"
            type="STRING" value="true"/>
        <enrich>
            <source clone="true" type="inline">
                <disr:DisbursementResponse xmlns:disr="urn:Namespaces.user1.se:Service:FinancialManagement:Payment:Disbursement:0001">
                    <disr:ResponseCode>900</disr:ResponseCode>
                    <disr:Message>General error</disr:Message>
                </disr:DisbursementResponse>
            </source>
            <target action="replace" type="body"/>
        </enrich>
    </faultSequence>
</target>
<publishWSDL key="conf:user1/ESBConfig/Common/NetPosti/resources/DisbursementService0002.wsdl">
    <resource
        key="conf:user1/ESBConfig/Common/NetPosti/resources/Disbursement_0002.xsd" location="Disbursement_0002.xsd"/>
</publishWSDL>
```

```
[user1@ip-10-20-0-20 ~]$ netstat -pnlt
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             
State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 :::8245                     :::*                        
LISTEN      2454/java
tcp        0      0 :::8282                     :::*                        
LISTEN      2454/java
```

Comment: What do you get? 404? 500? 502? connection refused?

Comment: I'm getting `site can’t be reached... took too long to respond.... ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` in Chrome.

Comment: can you post your proxy service config?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct IP ? Also, please check if wso2 was able to bind to the given ports using netstat or similar command

Comment: Also, check firewall configurations.

Comment: @Bee, I've edited my post and added the proxy service config.

Comment: @Philippe Sevestre, I'm sure I'm using the correct IP since I can access the service thru its https endpoint. Also, wso2 service seems to be listening on the correct ports based on the result of nestat command (see above).

Comment: Can you enable wire logs and post the logs in both cases? http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html
Another option you can try is removing all content in the proxy service and have a simple `respond` mediator. Then see if it shows the same behavior.

Comment: Do you see the first log message in wso2carbon.log ? If at least this one is written, then we can safely discard a connectivity issue between the client and ESB. Also, it seems you're not setting the proxy target correctly. Where is the message created by the payload mediator supposed to be sent to: a backend service or back to the caller?

Comment: @Bee, I've checked the log4j.properties file but I can't enable the wire logs for now since i still need to ask for permission to do this. Will get back to you on this..

Comment: @PhilippeSevestre, I checked wso2carbon.log and found log entries in it but I think these are due to other users accessing the service thru its https endpoint. Regarding the proxy setting, I'm still new to wso2 and was just assigned to investigate the http access so I can't really answer your question. Anyways, I did another tests: accessed the service thru its http endpoint then checked http_access.log, found no log entries. After that, I accessed the service again using its https endpoint then checked http_access.log: found log entries corresponding to the time that I access the service.

Comment: Also, I tried telnet to check if the ports are really open. telnet to its http port (8282) failed and returned `No route to host` message. However, telnet to its https port (8245), HTTPS servlet transport (9445), and HTTP servlet transport (9765) are all OK.This could really be just a connectivity issue. However, the netstat results above showed the port 8282 is open. What do you think @PhilippeSevestre?

Comment: Are you issuing the telnet command at the same host running wso2 or from another one ? If it's that later, then it seems to be a firewall rules somewhere.

Comment: turned out this was only a firewall issue. port 8282 was blocked in wso2 firewall (iptables). thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 0):

turned out this was only a firewall issue. port 8282 was blocked in wso2 firewall (iptables). thanks for all answers!